# how to read utf-8 characters from SQlite database

Tags: android, database, utf-8, android-sqlite

I'm trying to read data from SQlite database which contains UTF-8 characters.The app is getting crash

Below is the code

```
 public void thread_test_1(){

 final SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_PATH, null);

 String db_path2 = DB_PATH.toString() ;



 Thread t = new Thread( new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
 SQLiteStatement st = db.compileStatement("SELECT * FROM T2 LIMIT 50");
 String res = st.simpleQueryForString();
 test_result("thread_test_1", res, "10");
 }
 });

 t.start();
 try {
 t.join();
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
 }
 }
```

Below is the log

```
01-29 15:20:34.689: E/dalvikvm(2848): Calling h_NativeMethodHelper
 01-29 15:20:34.697: E/dalvikvm(2848): Version returned : 10004
 01-29 15:20:34.809: E/dalvikvm(2848): JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table      
  overflow (max=512)
  01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): JNI local reference table (0xb92d36c8) dump:
01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): Last 10 entries (of 512):
01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 511: 0xa6212868    
 java.lang.Class<android.database.CursorWindow>
01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 510: 0xa67ce268 java.lang.String "anśāpana"
01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 509: 0xa67ce228 java.lang.String "अंशाप�... (6chars)
01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 508: 0xa67ce1e8 java.lang.String "anshatah"
01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 507: 0xa67ce1a8 java.lang.String "ansatah"
01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 506: 0xa67ce168 java.lang.String "anśataḥ"
01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 505: 0xa67ce128 java.lang.String "अंशतः"
 01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 504: 0xa67ce0e8 java.lang.String "ansha"
01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 503: 0xa67ce0b0 java.lang.String "ansa"
01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 502: 0xa67ce078 java.lang.String "anśa"
01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): Summary:
01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 6 of java.lang.Class (5 unique instances)
01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 504 of java.lang.String (504 unique instances)
01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 1 of java.lang.String[] (2 elements)
01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 1 of android.database.CursorWindow
01-29 15:20:34.809: E/dalvikvm(2848): Failed adding to JNI local ref table (has 512 
entries)
 01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
 01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0xa61d2938 self=0xb90d18a8
 01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): | sysTid=2848 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-
error:2] handle=-1216708448
 01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): | state=R schedstat=( 135605814 28854381 456 )     
utm=9 stm=3 core=0
 01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at   
android.database.CursorWindow.nativePutString(Native Method)
01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at android.database.CursorWindow.putString(CursorWindow.java:621)
 01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): atorg.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow(Native Method)
 01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java:855)
01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:840)
01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:66)
01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:165)

 01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): atorg.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:135)
  01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:197)
01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:237)
01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at org.sqlite.app.customsqlite.CustomSqlite.csr_test_1(CustomSqlite.java:184)
 01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at org.sqlite.app.customsqlite.CustomSqlite.run_the_tests(CustomSqlite.java:314)
01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
 01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
 01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
 01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
 01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
  01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-29 15:20:34.809: E/dalvikvm(2848): VM aborting
 01-29 15:20:34.809: A/libc(2848): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 2848 (pp.customsqlite)
01-29 15:20:34.689: E/dalvikvm(2848): Calling h_NativeMethodHelper
01-29 15:20:34.697: E/dalvikvm(2848): Version returned : 10004
 01-29 15:20:34.809: E/dalvikvm(2848): JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)
  01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): JNI local reference table (0xb92d36c8) dump:
   01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): Last 10 entries (of 512):
         01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 511: 0xa6212868 java.lang.Class<android.database.CursorWindow>
  01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 510: 0xa67ce268 java.lang.String "anśāpana"
  01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 509: 0xa67ce228 java.lang.String "अंशाप�... (6 chars)
   01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 508: 0xa67ce1e8 java.lang.String "anshatah"
  01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 507: 0xa67ce1a8 java.lang.String "ansatah"
  01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 506: 0xa67ce168 java.lang.String "anśataḥ"
   01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 505: 0xa67ce128 java.lang.String "अंशतः"
     01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 504: 0xa67ce0e8 java.lang.String "ansha"
     01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 503: 0xa67ce0b0 java.lang.String "ansa"
    01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 502: 0xa67ce078 java.lang.String "anśa"
    01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): Summary:
    01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 6 of java.lang.Class (5 unique instances)
 01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 504 of java.lang.String (504 unique instances)
    01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 1 of java.lang.String[] (2 elements)
  01-29 15:20:34.809: W/dalvikvm(2848): 1 of android.database.CursorWindow
   01-29 15:20:34.809: E/dalvikvm(2848): Failed adding to JNI local ref table (has 512 entries)
 01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
  01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0xa61d2938  self=0xb90d18a8
 01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): | sysTid=2848 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=-1216708448
  01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): | state=R schedstat=( 135605814 28854381 456 ) utm=9 stm=3 core=0
   01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at android.database.CursorWindow.nativePutString(Native Method)
  01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at android.database.CursorWindow.putString(CursorWindow.java:621)
  01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow(Native Method)
  01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java:855)
  01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:840)
 01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:66)
  01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:165)
  01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:135)
  01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:197)
  01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:237)
   01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at org.sqlite.app.customsqlite.CustomSqlite.csr_test_1(CustomSqlite.java:184)
    01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at org.sqlite.app.customsqlite.CustomSqlite.run_the_tests(CustomSqlite.java:314)
   01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
   01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
   01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
  01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
  01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
     01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    01-29 15:20:34.809: I/dalvikvm(2848): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   01-29 15:20:34.809: E/dalvikvm(2848): VM aborting
 01-29 15:20:34.809: A/libc(2848): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 2848 (pp.customsqlite)
```

Comment: can you add the code you use to retrieve the stirngs?

Comment: Hi daniel i have added the code now please go through it.
Thanks

Comment: it appears that your code is never called. and your app already fails while putting the strings into the db "at android.database.CursorWindow.nativePutString(Native Method)"

Comment: By default Sqlite can read UTF-8 Characters. All you have to do is while getting the data and saving it to the database you should take care of getting utf-8 characters or strings.

Comment: Hi Daniel ... There is a method which set value to DB_PATH and it works perfect. Problem is occurring in some cases of words which don't have UTF-8 characters. like   अ / ए / ऐ
ऐफ्गैनस्टैन / ऐफ्गैनिस्टैन
अग्नी
अमेरक / अमेरिक / अमेरिक
ऐब्नॉर्मल्सी